# RIA Services Intellisense broken?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, ria

I am new to RIA services.  I downloaded a sample application called IssueVision which has server-side metadata classes in a class library, and client-side versions of those classes in a Silverlight class library.

The Silverlight class library does not (and cannot) reference the server side library, but it declares the classes as "partial" and the project compiles fine.  However, Intellisense does not recognize the partial relationship and it throws a multitude of errors in the client-side code files saying "the type or namespace name could not be found", etc.

1. How do these partial classes work?  How can you declare a partial class across multiple assemblies when neither references the other?
2. How can I fix Intellisense support for RIA services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've figured out:

1. The partial classes are created in the client project using the RIA services link in the project property page.  They are hidden just like the XAML .g.cs generated files.
2. I was seemingly able to resolve the Intellisense bug at both my home and work PC by installing the RIA Services Toolkit.